# Don't execute a function until a HTML <input> required Attribute is TRUE

Tags: javascript, required

I want to know if there's a way to execute a JS function until a required attribute returns TRUE. And if it's possible, how.

I have those required inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="sen1" placeholder="Nombre" required>
<input type="number" name="tre_1" placeholder="Segundos" required>
```

And I send the value with another input and a function:

```
<input type="button" name="Ok" value="Guardar" onclick="Dale();">
```

Finally, this is my function:

```
function Dale(){

var number1 = [];

number1.push(document.myform.sen1.value);
number1.push(document.myform.log1.value);
number1.push(document.myform.p_v1.value);
number1.push(document.myform.tre_1.value);
number1.push(document.myform.sds1.value);
number1.push(document.myform.pan1.value);

doSend( document.myform.start.value );

doSend( number1 );

doSend( document.myform.end.value );
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you wanto to watch for, could you explain further ?

Comment: You can use setInterval and have the function run until whichever value you are looking for is true with an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change three things:

1) change your submit button into `type="submit"`

2) remove `onClick` from submit button

3) add `onSubmit` on `<form>` tag

After that HTML5 validation should work as expected and do not call your `onSubmit` function unless conditions are not met.

If you do not want to make above changes, you have to implement your own validation inside `Dale` function, checking if inputs are empty or not.

Comment: Your welcome! Accept my answer if you found it useful :)